# Matching words and valid sub-words in elasticseach

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I've been working with ElasticSearch within an existing code base for a few days, so I expect that the answer is easy once I know what I'm doing. I want to extend a search to yield the same results when I search with a compound word, like "eyewitness", or its component words separated by a whitespace, like "eye witness".

For example, I have a catalog of toy cars that includes both "firetruck" toys and "fire truck" toys. I would like to ensure that if someone searched on either of these terms, the results would include both the "firetruck" and the "fire truck" entries.

I attempted to do this at first with the "fuzziness" of a match, hoping that "fire truck" would be considered one transform away from "firetruck", but that does not work: ES fuzziness is per-word and will not add or remove whitespace characters as a valid transformation.

I know that I could do some brute-forcing before generating the query by trying to come up with additional search terms by breaking big words into smaller words and also joining smaller words into bigger words and checking all of them against a dictionary, but that falls apart pretty quickly when "fuzziness" and proper names are part of the task.

It seems like this is exactly the kind of thing that ES should do well, and that I simply don't have the right vocabulary yet for searching for the solution.

Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

there are two things you could could do:

1. you could split words into their compounds, i.e. `firetruck` would be split into two tokens `fire` and `truck`, [see here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-compound-word-tokenfilter.html)
2. you could use n-grams, i.e. for 4 grams the original `firetruck` get split into the tokens `fire`, `iret`, `retr`, `etru`, `truc`, `ruck`. In queries, the scoring function helps you ending up with pretty decent results. Check out [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/ngrams-compound-words.html).

Always remember to do the same tokenization on both the analysis and the query side.

I would start with the ngrams and if that is not good enough you should go with the compounds and split them yourself - but that's a lot of work depending on the vocabulary you have under consideration.

hope the concepts and the links help, fricke